# 508/ADA compliancy with lightboxes

Tags: accessibility, lightbox, section508, nvda

I'm currently trying to develop a lightbox that will be 508/ADA compliant; to achieve this, I need to make a lightbox appear (already done) and then have a reader such as NVDA read what's on the lightbox instead of changing focus to the page-text directly behind the lightbox and read that. In a more concise way - have the lightbox appear onload, have the focus remain on the lightbox and have NVDA read what's on the lightbox without going back to the background. I'll keep updating should I come to an answer before someone else provides one.

There is no solution for this problem at this moment - 
This is a NVDA problem with Aria-hidden not being properly recognized.http://www.nvda-project.org/ticket/2706 // http://www.nvda-project.org/ticket/2117 -

The solution I propose:

Create an iFrame - or DIV -  that expands or collapses / Appear or Dissapper only when a message is meant to be displayed. This will create a "focusable" area which can then be the point of reference for NVDA. I'll continue to work on a JavaScript/JQuery solution for this problem.

Comment: There two articles should get you started: http://juicystudio.com/article/custom-built_dialogs.php and http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/02/12/making-an-accessible-dialog-box/

Comment: Ryan, Thanks so much for sharing these resources, they will certainly help me. I'll have a coded solution soon. Best.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `role="alertdialog"` or `role="dialog"`. This helps the screenreader to pick read the contents of the lightbox.